# Emberjs store error-Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'trasitionTo'

Tags: ember.js

I am a beginner to Emberjs and please go through the code and please guide me where am I wrong.

.js file

```
Sample = Ember.Application.create();


Sample.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('view');
    this.resource('add');
})
Add = Ember.Object.extend();
View = Ember.Object.extend();

Sample.AddNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return Sample.Add.createRecord();
    }
});

Sample.ViewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
Sample.AddController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content:[],
    save:function(){
        this.get("model.transaction");
        this.get("target").trasitionTo('view');
    }
});

Sample.ViewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

Sample.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision:11,
    adapter: DS.LSAdapter.create(),
});

Sample.Add =  DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr("string"),
  desig: DS.attr("string"),
  age: DS.attr("integer")
});

.html file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/libs/localstorage_adapter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/sample.js"></script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Demo application</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h1>Welcome to Demo!</h1>
  {{#link-to 'add'}}Add Member{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'view'}}View Members{{/link-to}}
  {{outlet}}
  </script>

   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name ='add'>

  <h1>Add member!</h1>  
  <form {{action 'save' on='submit'}}>

  <br>{{#view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name" placeholder= "Enter the name"}}{{/view}}</br>
  <br>{{#view Ember.TextField valueBinding="desig" placeholder= "Enter the designation"}}{{/view}}</br>
  <br>{{#view Ember.TextField valueBinding="age" placeholder= "Enter the age"}}{{/view}}</br>
  <br><button {{action "save"}}>Add Member</button></br>   

  </form>  

  </script>

   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name ='view'>
   <h3><strong>All Registered Members!</strong>
   <br></br>
   {{#each controller}}

   <br>{{name}}</br>
   <br>{{desig}}</br>
   <br>{{age}}</br>
   {{else}}
   No members registered yet! :(

   {{/each}}

   </script>

    enter code here

</body>
</html>
```

After I click the 'Add Member button I am getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'trasitionTo'

Answer (score 0):

You have a record Add which it is using for handling the click. Can you rename Add record to something else?

```
Add = Ember.Object.extend();//use someother name instead of Add
```

Instead name it something else like MyAddRecord or something else. Once you do that you should will get correct or relevant error message.

Comment: There are 2 things here: 1. records 2. resource. In your original code, you are naming both record and resource as Add and that was causing the issue. My suggestion was to change the record name to something else. You don't need to change the route etc...

Comment: I changed Add to AddMember.

AddMember = Ember.Object.extend();
ViewMember = Ember.Object.extend();

Sample.AddMemberNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return Sample.AddMember.createRecord();
    }
});

Sample.ViewMemberController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
Sample.AddMemberController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    save:function(){
        this.get("model.transaction").commit();
        this.get('router.target').trasitionTo('view');
    }
});
But I am getting -Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'save'error though I defined the method in controller